# UITableviewCell Bottom Left & Right corner radius

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have applied bottom left and right corner radius to my `UITableViewCell`
and it works fine but the width of that `cell` is decreased.I have constraints applied in the `containerView` of that `cell`. Whats the reason behind this ?

[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RateChartTableViewCell *cell1 = (RateChartTableViewCell *)cell;

    if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath 
    bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell1.containerView.bounds byRoundingCorners:( UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        maskLayer.frame = tableView.bounds;
        maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
        cell1.containerView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
        cell1.containerView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because cell's size is changed but `maskLayer` still keeps old size. In my opinion, to fix it, each time cell's size is changed, remove and add `maskLayer` again.

*RateChartTableViewCell*

```
@interface RateChartTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer* maskLayer;
... other properties

@end

@implementation RateChartTableViewCell

- (void)configureBorders {
  UIBezierPath* maskPath =
  [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                        byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft |
                                           UIRectCornerBottomRight)
                              cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
  _maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
  _maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
  _maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
  self.layer.mask = _maskLayer;
  self.clipsToBounds = YES;
  self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];

  [_maskLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
  [self configureBorders];
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
  [super prepareForReuse];

  [_maskLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
}

@end
```

*ViewController*

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  RateChartTableViewCell* cell = // Initialize cell

  // Do other things

  if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 4) {
    [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]; // You can move this line to |viewDidLoad|
    [cell configureBorders];
  }

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: It works but when I scroll the `tableview` after that only.

Comment: Updated my answer with using `celForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: it's the same. I need to scroll the `tableView` .

Comment: The `cornerRadius` happens but the `cell` width is lesser than what it should be.

Comment: I think it's a problem with `containerView`. Try my updated answer

Comment: The `containerView` has leading and trailing constraints.

Comment: if I can add some shadow to the bottom of the bottom `cell ` ?

Comment: In this case you should add shadow to whole tableView

Answer (score 0):

maskLayer.frame = tableView.bounds; maybe wrong. You can change it:
maskLayer.frame = cell1.bounds;
Hope it will help you.